# Write each line to a file with a csv extension

Tags: python, logging

I am currently writing to a log file via the below classic way; to write my values that are populated and handled elsewhere in my application.

**When I change the file extension to .csv, it outputs outside of cells, messy.**

```
old_stdout = sys.stdout
log_file = open("./logs/metrics.log","w") # I want this to be excel instead, when I change to csv it outputs outside of cells, messy
sys.stdout = log_file

# this to be one excel row (or record)

print(f"Total Records Found #{total_records} records") # this to be excel cell
print(f"Records Processing #{num_valid_records} records") # this to be excel cell
print(f"Records Deemed Invalid (skipped) #{num_invalid_records} records") # this to be excel cell
success_rate = num_valid_records / total_records * 100
print("Sucess Rate:") # this to be excel cell
print(success_rate) # this to be excel cell
```

then it prints like this: **(but how can I map this to excel cells?)**

```
Total Records Found #351 records
Records Processing #350 records
Records Deemed Invalid (skipped) #1 records
Sucess Rate:
99.71509971509973
```

---

**I am wondering; how I can instead print these into an excel file, into cells as one row**

Comment: you can use the `csv` module: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.writer

Comment: Write each line to a file with a csv extension - e.g. `thefile.csv`

Comment: @wwii exactly, that's what I'm trying to do!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files ... https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Python is famous for having great documentation with thorough examples.

```
from csv import DictWriter

with open("./logs/metrics.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    csv_writer = DictWriter(f, ['total', 'processed', 'skipped', 'success_rate'])
    csv_writer.writeheader()

    success_rate = num_valid_records / total_records * 100
    csv_writer.writerow(dict(total=total_records,
                             processed=num_valid_records,
                             skipped=num_invalid_records,
                             success_rate=num_valid_records / total_records * 100))
```

Comment: Yeah! That's exactly what I was trying to do... now the problem is, everytime I run the script it is not maintaining the old, and writing the new to a 'new line' - instead it seems to be update the same line...?

Comment: I know it's a different question -- but any pointers on getting a new line to write with each time the script runs?

Comment: @PeterGibbons you'll need to seek to the end of the file, and not write the headers again, then write rows like normal